# Cannot resolve symbol QLibrary

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Открываю .dll с помощью QLibrary (проверяю, открывается успешно). Затем, прежде добавив в хедер этой .dll

```
#ifdef Q_WS_WIN
#define MY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_EXPORT
#endif
```

(как сказано в мануале), и, добавив в хедере, к функциям, которые хочу вызвать

```
extern "C" MY_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

Например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
пытаюсь, собственно говоря, их вызвать таким образом:

```
    Geocom_orig=new QLibrary("GeoComS2K.dll");
    Geocom_orig->load();
    qDebug()<<Geocom_orig->isLoaded();
    typedef GRC_TYPE (*MyComInit)();
    MyComInit ComInit=(MyComInit) Geocom_orig->resolve("COM_Init");
    qDebug()<<Geocom_orig->errorString();
        if(ComInit)
            qDebug()<<"OK";

        int returnedCode=ComInit();
```

errorString() выводит ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема? Вроде бы всё сделано правильно...
Единственное, что мне кажется странным, то что он выводит "СOM_Init\" как неопределенный символ.

**UPD:**
Прошу прощения, не перевел кодировку консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, я не очень понимаю, он действительно ищет именно "COM_Init\"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наткнулся на дельный совет попробовать открыть .dll с помощью утилиты http://dependencywalker.com/ (вот сам топик https://forum.qt.io/topic/8820/solved-cannot-resolve-the-symbols-from-a-custom-dll/2). С помощью которой можно узнать структуру .dll, а заодно и имена функций, которые можно вызвать, потому что они могут иметь имя отличное от того, что указано в хедере. В данном случае функция `COM_Init` имела такое интересное имя:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен, если в комментариях объяснят почему она и некоторые другие функции имеют такие странные имена.

Comment: Это формат наименования символов С++, называется C++ name mangling, принята эта система из-за того что перегрузка функций в С++ подразумевает возможность существования более одной функции с одинаковыми именами, что сделало бы правильное разрешение символов невозможным.

Comment: Иными словами, эта библиотека содержит символы не в формате "C", а в формате С++.

Comment: @Vladimir Pavluk , спасибо. в таком случае существует ли какой-то более нативный метод узнать имя функции для экспорта ?

Comment: возможно таковой и существует, но я о нем ничего не знаю. Проблема в том, что разные компиляторы делают это по-разному.